# EF6 Code First Migrations: migrating events

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a code-first scenario with migrations enabled, `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` is disabled, and the DB initializer is set to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`. I'd like to "catch" Migration events for logging purposes.

I tried to do it in the `Seed()` but it's called every single run, regardless of whether the underlying database needs a migration to match the model or not.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: This is properly not what you are looking for, but there is a `[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]` table that contains information about all migrations that have been applied to the database.

Comment: Yes I know but it does not contain (for example) information about timestamp of migration. I need to log migration as EF fires it

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1)

Check if you need migration:

```
  var migrator = new DbMigrator(new DbMigrationsConfiguration());

  // If any migration is required then Count will be greater than 0
  // 0 means no migration required
  if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Count() > 0)
  {
    // Fire your event here!
  }
```

Soultion 2)
Use a logging decorator to log progress, in this use case you do not need the event.

```
public class MyLogger : System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsLogger
{
    public override void Info(string message)
    {
        // Short status messages come here
    }

    public override void Verbose(string message)
    {
        // The SQL text and other info comes here
    }

    public override void Warning(string message)
    {
        // Warnings and other bad messages come here
    }
}
```

To migrate to latest version, you have to call it like that:

```
 DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(new MyConfiguration());
 MigratorLoggingDecorator logger = new MigratorLoggingDecorator(migrator, new MyLogger());
 // This line will call the migration + logging
 logger.Update();
```

Extra info:

You can create your custom MigratorLoggingDecorator decroator like that:

```
MyMigratorLoggingDecorator: MigratorLoggingDecorator {

    internal override Upgrade(IEnumerable<string> pendingMigrations, string   targetMigrationId, string lastMigrationId)
    {
     // Fire your event here!
     base.Upgrade(..)
    }
..}
```